# Replacing one substring multiple times without looping? (using an array of replacements)

Tags: php

Is it possible to replace one substring multiple times in a string, but with different replacements? I know this can be done with a loop and `str_replace()`, but I swear there has to be an easier way!

Example:

```
<?php
// Returns '1.2.3';
echo str_replace('%', array(1, 2, 3), '%.%.%');
?>
```

Do I really need to start a loop on the string, and then replace one match at a time? That seems like a sloppy way to do something that should be much simpler. What am I missing?

Comment: Might this be a job for [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or even [vsprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php)?

Comment: is your original string a literal `%`? Or was it just an example?

Comment: sprintf or vsprintf should be turned into an answer

Comment: It's just an example. I envisioned this: str_replace(WHATWEAREREPLACING, ARRAYOFREPLACEMENTS, HAYSTACK)

Comment: And I'll look into `vsprintf()`. It looks like it may work unless a literal '%s' appears in my string. Though this is unlikely, I'll hold out just in case a more universal answer is given. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by Scuzzy in the comments, `vsprintf()` turned out to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work using str_ireplace (note the i). I am not sure but it should work like this: `str_ireplace(array('%', '%', '%'), array(1, 2, 3), '%.%.%')`. I do not have a way of testing it right now tho.

Comment: Though this would work, it's not a very good way of solving this. Not only would I need to make an array duplicating the same value, but I'd have to know the number of parameters beforehand, and then loop through those to build the first parameter's array anyway.